# R: want random records from multiple output files

Tags: r, csv, gis

I'm very new to using R, so I'm not sure if there is a simple solution to what I need.

I have created folders for 3 different variables in multiple locations. For example, in each of folders A, B, and C there are multiple output files named something like Folder A: A_1, A_2, A_3, Folder B: B_1, B_2, B_3, Folder C: C_1, C_2, C_3. Each file is a .csv file

I want to create a new script which will take each of these files and give me 6 random records with all the variables so that I can compare the output to my original set of data.

Will this require creating new files or can they just be opened within R? What are some of the key functions that I will need to use?

-edit-
Folder A has 11 files, Folder B has 11 files, and Folder C has 6 files.
A single file from folder A has 2154 rows and the rest of the files are similar in size. I would like 6 random records/rows from each file to be shown in some way whether it is in R or in a separate file.

Comment: You did not sufficiently explain what the files contain or what you are trying to randomize. Do you want to read random files? In that case you need to use `list.files` `sample` and `read.table` or `read.csv` something like that. If you want to read random "records" from files, you need to read files then take random lines I guess? That depends on what the files actually contain

Comment: why is this tagged with Python?

Answer (score 0):

To find all the `.csv` files within a working directory (including subdirectories), you can use `list.files` with some arguments:

```
all_csvs <- list.files(pattern = ".csv$", recursive = TRUE)
```

The `all_csvs` object will then be a character vector that contains all your filenames.

You should be able to read in all of your files into one dataframe at once using something like so:

```
library(tidyverse)
all_data <- map_df(all_csvs, ~read_csv(.))
```

You could read in the first 10 rows of each `.csv` files with this:

```
first_10 <- map_df(all_csvs, ~read_csv(., n_max = 10))
```

If you want to take 10 random rows from each `.csv`, try something like this:

```
random_10 <- map_df(all_csvs, ~read_csv(.) %>% sample_n(10))
```